# Does calling a struct method with a dynamic parameter cause it to get copied?

Tags: c#, struct, dynamic

I am trying to wrap my head around this behavior that I am seeing. I know that the structs get copied when they are moved around as they are ValueType. But I cannot understand why this sample code fails. Here is just a simple C# code to demonstrate the issue:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        private MyStruct ms;

        public MyClass()
        {
            ms = new MyStruct("");
        }

        public void Add(dynamic d)
        {
            ms.Add(d);
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("L: " + ms.GetLength());
        }
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
        private dynamic[] items;

        public MyStruct(string junk)
        {
            items = new dynamic[0];
        }

        public int GetLength()
        {
            return items.Length;
        }

        public void Add(dynamic d)
        {
            Array.Resize<dynamic>(ref items, items.Length + 1);
            items[items.Length - 1] = d;
        }
    }
```

By running the code below, I get wrong result. In debugger I can see that the item is added but it does not persist, which means I see "L: 0" twice (instead of "L: 0" and "L: 1"):

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.Print();
mc.Add("Test");
mc.Print();
```

I noticed that if in MyClass.Add, the ms.Add is called with a type other than "dynamic" ("string", for instance) it works fine. Something like this:

```
public void Add(string d)
{
   ms.Add(d);
}
```

or even this:

```
public void Add(dynamic d)
{
   string s = d.ToString();
   ms.Add(s);
}
```

It makes me think that I am probably working on a copy, but if that is the case, I do not understand why. I am accessing the field directly so I do not expect this to happen.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Reflection always involves boxing - why do you expect otherwise? (The struct you have is quite insane... having mutable value type with partially reference semantic.... is going to make your life *interesting*).

Comment: At runtime `dynamic` == `object` just with runtime binding of all member accesses. So `dynamic` also means that your struct values will be boxed.

Comment: Please don't do `string s = d.ToString();`. That's bad when `d` is `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operation with a `dynamic` type (including call with a `dynamic` parameter) uses runtime-binding and thus ultimately reflection - and as @AlexeiLevenkov noted in his comment this involves boxing.

You can prove this by adding an overload

```
public void Add(string d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add(String)");
    Array.Resize<dynamic>(ref items, items.Length + 1);
    items[items.Length - 1] = d;
}
```

to `MyStruct`. This produces the output

```
L: 0 
AddString 
L: 0
```

If you have a look at the generated IL, this includes:

```
ldfld   MyClass.ms
ldarg.1 
callvirt    Action <CallSite, MyStruct, Object>.Invoke (CallSite, MyStruct, Object)
```

So the struct will be passed as parameter to an Action ultimatedly performing the call to the dynamically determined overload of `ms.Add`. This parameter passing is where a copy is created.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your structures. But that's OK, everyone had to go through this process.

1. Why are you using `MyClass` as class, but `MyStruct` as struct? Fundamentally, your structure has no difference than a class, so its better to define it as its own class.
2. Is there a particular reason why you are using `Array.Resize<dynamic>(ref items, items.Length + 1);` inside `MyStruct`? Why don't you use a simple `List`? If you use an array, you will have a hard time to re-define its size. Use List, and then just use add.
3. There is a keyword: **const** that you can use to make your parameters constant, and not get copied when called as a parameter of a function. It might help you in the future.
4. In your class `Myclass`, you should use the reserved keyword **this** to clarify that you are referring to the inner object of the class

```cs
public void Add(string d)
{
   this.ms.Add(d);
}
```

5. If you are new to C# or coming from another background (C or C++ or Java), its better to not use **dynamic** that loosely. You might get some serious memory allocation problems if you don't have experience with it. It's better if you decide/know the type before hand. If you don't but you know what could be the types, you can use an **if** with **IsInstanceOfType**.

Comment: I would disagree with the first item on the list. A class is stored differently in memory than a struct, which can lead to significant performance differences, especially if the objects are only present in the scope for a short time. I would not make a general statement that a class is better than a struct.